# Property of a euclidean map

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why an euclidean map defined onto a domain $R$, so a map $\delta\colon R\smallsetminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{N}$, satisfies $\delta(a)\leq\delta(ab)$ for every $a,b\in R\smallsetminus\{0\}$?

In some books, this property does not belongs to the definition of euclidean domain, and now I have to prove it.

Comment: Consider the discussion of (EF2) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition).

Comment: @Lorenzo Since anon gave you the answer, maybe you can answer your own question and close it, for the record :)

Comment: Ok, but I'm going to answer by copying what the link above says. I tried to do the euclidean division between $b$, $a$ and $ab$, but it does not work.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423963/question-about-the-euclidean-ring-definition/427165#427165)